# How do I order XMLElements within an XmlArray?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I was wondering how I would order an XmlElement within an XmlArray. For example, I want `Car1` to be the first item underneath the XmlArray `Cars` and `Car2` to be the second item. I've tried `[XmlElement("Car1", Order = 1)]` and `[XmlElement("Car1", Order = 3)]` and neither worked. What would be the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

```
[XmlRoot("Items")]
public class Items
{
    [XmlElement("Owner", Order = 1)]
    public String Owner { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("Cars", Order = 2)]
    [XmlArrayItem("Car")]
    public List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();
}

public class Car
{
    [XmlElement("Car1")] // Order = 1 within "Car"
    public String Car1{ get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Car2")] // // Order = 2 within "Car"
    public String Car2{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you want as output <Items>
  <Owner>test</Owner>
  <Cars>
    <Car1>c1</Car1>
    <Car2>c2</Car2>
  </Cars>
</Items>

Answer (score 0):

here you have to change the class structure

```
 [XmlRoot("Items")]
public class Items
{
    [XmlElement("Owner", Order = 1)]
    public String Owner { get; set; }

      [XmlArray("Cars", Order = 2)]
      public Car[] carList { get; set; }
}


public class Car
{

    [XmlElement("Car1")] // Order = 1 within "Car"
    public String Car1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Car2")] // // Order = 2 within "Car"
    public String Car2 { get; set; }
}
```

then use like below code.

```
Car c = new Car { Car1 = "c1", Car2 = "c2" };


Items item = new Items { Owner = "test", carList = new Car[] { c} };
```

Output:
[image: output]